# .htaccess rules not properly working

Tags: php, .htaccess

My .htaccess file has a rule to make links like

`localhost/post.php?id=some-post`

be rewritten to

`localhost/post/some-post`

The code is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^post.php/([a-z0-9-]+)$ post.php?id=$1 [L]
```

That works well. However, now all embedded links in the .php files go to 
localhost/post/ first.

Example: If i go to a post, my style.css does not load. The post is searching the file in http://localhost/post/css/style.css, instead of http://localhost/css/style.css.

The same happens with images in /img/ folder, fonts in /font/ folder, etc. It now looks for everything in an extra post/ folder, even extra php files in an /admin folder..

Is there any rule that will allow me to fix this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: try adding a `/` before `post.php?id=$1`

Comment: I tried, but i got an error in the page :/

Comment: :( I never go near WP so I find it's config and layout a bit confusing. Sorry @J Gal - there are lots of SO users that know lots about WP so hopefully one of them will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can fix that easily. Here are 2 options for it.

You can add a base tag to the `<head>` section of your html.

```
<base href="/" />
```

Or you can prepend your css path with a `/` in the href

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/style.css">
```

For good measure, I would also update my rule to ignore real files and real directories so that if you add any other seo friendly rules it won't do weird stuff.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#if request is for a real file or directory do nothing.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#else all other rules go here for pretty URLs
RewriteRule ^post/([a-z0-9-]+)$ post.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The <base href="/" /> worked like a charm. Adding the / before my css did nothing however, and the 2 RewriteCond and RewriteRule you added make all my posts go to http://localhost/post/index.php and give an error :/ No idea why.